# returnUrl in Partial Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a view that displays the assets for an account.

```
@{
    string returnUrl = returnUrl = Url.Action("Details", "AccountEntries", new { page = Model.Pages.Page }, null);
}

...

@foreach (ViewDetails.ViewAsset item in Model.ViewAssets)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item.Asset.Description
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Asset.Amount.ToGBString()
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Assets", new { id = item.Asset.Id, returnUrl = returnUrl }, null)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

I want to dynamically insert (create) rows using partial views and **ajax**.

```
@{
    string returnUrl = returnUrl = Url.Action("Details", "AccountEntries", new { page = Model.Pages.Page }, null);
}

...

@foreach (ViewDetails.ViewAsset item in Model.ViewAssets)
{
    @Html.Partial("_Asset", item)
}
```

with a **partial view**:

```
@model ViewDetails.ViewAsset

<tr>
    <td>
        @Model.Asset.Description
    </td>
    <td>
        @Model.Asset.Amount.ToGBString()
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Assets", new { id = Model.Asset.Id, returnUrl = returnUrl }, null)
    </td>
</tr>
```

and **AJAX**:

```
public ActionResult MyAjaxAction(MyViewModel model)
{

    return PartialView("_Asset", model);
}
```

PROBLEM: My `returnUrl` is generated in the main view, and I don't know how to use it in the partial view for both the view and the ajax call.

For the view, I could pass it through using `ViewDataDictionary`, but then how do I do the same with the **Ajax** call? Do I send the Url in the **Ajax** call or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Don't you want to use your ViewModel for this case?

Comment: You're saying I should store the returnUrl in the view model?

Comment: Yeap, why not? if you pass int to your partialView.

Comment: I have considered that. But I assume the returnUrl needs to be in the main view and then referenced in the class given to the partial view. And then Ajax will still have to send the returnUrl to the action.

Comment: You basically have 2 options. Either add this field to `ViewModel` or store this field in `js` global variable and then get it with `js` when you load `partialView`. I recommend you to store your info in `ViewModel` just becouse it's cleaner and easy to maintain in future.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the returnUrl in the ViewBag and access it in your partial views.